# How can I let users select existing media entities in a webform?

Tags: media, webforms

I am a beginner in drupal and I am creating a course form I would like you to help me with a field in the webform. I need to add a field where users can add an image and documents but from the files that I have in drupal media, not from my computer. I tried with webform entity view and file entity browser but they did not work for me, I can upload my images and documents but from the computer and it is not what I want.
Or maybe I did not use it correctly, I hope for your help, thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah first you need to upload them from the computer that they appear in the media library. You can't select already uploaded media you say?

Comment: Are you using the Media module that ships with core? It sounds like you need to also use the Media Library module that also ships with core. This will provide you with a library of previously uploaded files that you can reuse on your system

Comment: @Jaypan I am using an image field that comes by default in the webform and only allows me to load images from my computer but not from files already saved in drupal

Comment: I'm using the image field, but it only loads the images from my computer and not from my drupal files. @leymannx

Comment: I don't use Webform, so I'm not sure if you can use Media entities with it.

Answer (score 0):

Guys use the field type Entity radio and select the type of content you need, in this case it was medium, and it brought me the values that I have in drupal, thank you very much for your help